# Return :checked checkboxes value with is()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have sets of checkboxes so I assigned each set in a variable.

```
var $set1 = $('.suppliers'), $set2 = $('.products'), $set3 = $('.customer')//etc...
```

Then somewhere on my code, I want to put each set :checked values in an array:

```
var set1Arr = [];

$set1.is(':checked').each(function() {
   set1Arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

But nothing is returned, I also debugged and on console it says Object has no method 'each'. 
I tried using not(':checked') and it is working okay, it returned the unchecked values.

Comment: `$set1.filter(':checked').each(...)`, [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter(':checked')`.

`not()` is not the opposite of `is()`, but it's `!.is()`. On the other hand `filter()` is the opposite of `not()`.

---

You just misunderstood how both methods work.

`is()` checks if one element in the current set of elements matches the selector, and returns a `boolean`:

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
    //if at least one checkbox is checked do something...
}
```

`not()` is a filtering method, it checks each element with the selector and returns only those that do not match the selector.

Comment: I see okay so they are different method this good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create array

```
var set1Arr = $set1.filter(':checked').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();
```

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)  returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .filter()

```
var set1Arr = [];
$set1.filter(':checked').each(function() {
   set1Arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

or better

```
var set1Arr =  $set1.filter(':checked').map(function() {
   return this.value
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$set1.each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        set1Arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$set1.each(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
       set1Arr.push($(this).val());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var checkboxValue = $(this).prop('checked');
```

**or**

```
$(this).is(':checked'); //return boolean
```